# Exrapolation in scipy's griddate with nearest neighbor method

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to use nearest neighbor method for the interpolation of a 2-D image. I am using the `griddata` function from `scipy.interpolate`. The problem is, unlike the `linear` and `cubic` methods, the `nearest` method does not support an extrapolation fill value, and I end up with an incorrect image.

My code is rather long, but here is the basic and relevant lines I am using for the interpolation:

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
vals = griddata(tuple(skewed_coords), self.values.ravel(), tuple(mesh_coords), method='nearest', fill_value=-1)
```

The result with nearest neighbor method just extends the borders of the image for extrapolation: 
[image: Nearest Neighbor Interpolation]

**Desired result:**
The following is the result I am expecting, which I obtain when I specify `method='linear'`. However I would like to use `method='nearest'` if possible, since it is faster.

[image: Linear interpolation]

Comment: The distinction between extrapolation and interpolation is important with `linear`.  But with `nearest`, that isn't a valid distinction.  A (40,10) is still nearest to one one point or other in the image.  How about applying a `fill` after the fact?

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer. Yes, this is what I am doing now, but I was hoping there is a builtin way to do it.